# Google Custom Search API

Tags: java, google-api

How should one approach on using Google Custom Search API using JAVA?
What is the appropriate use of Google Search Appliance API?

Comment: really vague question...

Answer (score 3):

Here is google custom search API Example. you need to download Libraries and example is here

```
public class Custom {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException  {
        String key="Replace with your API key";
        String qry="batman";// search key word
        URL url = new URL(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?               
                key="+key+"&cx="Replace with unique ID"&q="+ qry + 
                "&alt=json");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println(url);
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {

            if(output.contains("\"link\": \"")){                
                String link=output.substring(output.indexOf("\"link\": \"")+
                       ("\"link\": \"").length(), output.indexOf("\","));
                System.out.println(link);
            }     
        }
        conn.disconnect();   
    }

  }
```

Comment: the 403 is due to the API key. You need to create a new one from the Google Developper Console